# SQL Query With Row_Number, order by and where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle10g, row-number

I have the following SQL query:

```
select
     ID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2
from
     (select ID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, row_number() over (order by 2 DESC) NO from A_TABLE)
where
     NO between 0 and 100
```

What I am trying to do is to select the first 100 records of the query

```
select ID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2 from ATABLE order by 2 DESC
```

And here are the problems:

1. Apparently, the `order by` clause is not working. I've noticed that I have to add another `order by 2 DESC` clause, just after `(...) from ATABLE`, for my query to work. Is there something I do wrong? Or is it expected behaviour?
2. How can I add a `where` clause? Let's say I need to select only the first 100 records of the table `where COLUMN1 like '%value%'`. I've tried adding the where clause after `(...) from ATABLE` but it produced an error...

Help? Thanks.

PS: I'm using Oracle 10g R2.

Comment: Can you actually include the other queries that you've tried instead of just explaining them? It might make it easier to spot the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

rownum is a pseudo column that counts rows in the result set *after* the where clause has been applied.

Is this what you're trying to get?

```
SELECT *
FROM ( 
    SELECT id, column1, column2
    FROM atable ORDER BY 2 DESC
) 
WHERE ROWNUM < 100;
```

Because it's a pseudo column that is strictly a counter of rows resulting from the where clause it will not allow you to do pagination (i.e. between 200 & 300).

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (SELECT a.*, rownum rnum FROM
     (SELECT id, column1, column2 FROM atable ORDER BY 2 DESC) a WHERE rownum <= 300)
WHERE rnum >= 200;
```

Comment: And me too. :-)

Answer (score 4):

[Check out this Oracle FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/can_one_retrieve_only_rows_x_to_y_from_a_table). In particular this part:

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT a.*, rownum RN 
      FROM (SELECT * 
                         FROM t1 ORDER BY key_column) a
         WHERE rownum <=7)
 WHERE rn >=5
```

Comment: For those that are interested, this is called a TOP-N query

Comment: I know about top-n but right now it is not helping me at all, considering that I have to fetch exactly n records between value1 and value2.

Comment: I thought that is what my query did :)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question: Don't use a column number in your order by clause, but use the column name.
I don't fully understand your second question, because adding a WHERE in your most inner SELECT should do the trick:

```
select ID
,      COLUMN1
,      COLUMN2
from  (select ID
       ,      COLUMN1
       ,      COLUMN2
       ,      row_number() over (order by COLUMN1 DESC) NO
       from   A_TABLE
       where  COLUMNX LIKE '%SOME VALUE%'
      )
where  NO between 0 and 100
```

P.S. (to willcodejavaforfood) I think using row_number() is better when you want the rows to be ordered. It saves an inner view (big win for readability).

Comment: +1 for the ROW_NUMBER() usage which is easier to understand.
-1 for your P.S. suggesting the ORDER BY in an inner view won't work - willcodejavaforfood's suggestion works perfectly well.

Comment: Edited my P.S. (removed the part about using an order by in a sub-query) because i have no prove and it will be hard to construct (if possible...)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

```
Select top 100 ID, Column1, Column2
From A_Table
where Column1 like '%value%'
order by Column2 desc
```

Comment: What if I need to select the rows between row_num 200 and 300 ?
This is why I tried to use row_num in the first place...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you were using Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will get the limited record from the oracle database without the usage of `rownum`

```
select * from 
    ( select ,column1,column2,row_number() over (order by columnName) as rnum 
      from table_name) 
where rnum between 5 and 10;
```