# Select first result only

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have written the following query:

```
SELECT CLIENT.CLIENTNO, CLIENT.CNAME, TOTALS.TOTAL 
FROM CLIENT, (SELECT CLIENTNO, SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL 
              FROM PURCHASE GROUP BY CLIENTNO) TOTALS 
WHERE CLIENT.CLIENTNO = TOTALS.CLIENTNO AND ROWNUM <= 1 
ORDER BY TOTALS.TOTAL DESC;
```

However it is giving me the wrong answer, but if I remove the `ROWNUM <= 1` clause, then the correct answer is at the top of the result set.

So what can I change in this query to make it produce the correct answer?

Thanks,
Alex.

EDIT: Forgot to say that I only want the query to return the the first result in the result set.

Comment: The problem is that the rownum is assigned before the dataset is sorted.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `ROWNUM` filter applies before the sorting. What you need to do is this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT CLIENT.CLIENTNO, CLIENT.CNAME, TOTALS.TOTAL 
  FROM CLIENT, (SELECT CLIENTNO, SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL 
                  FROM PURCHASE GROUP BY CLIENTNO) TOTALS 
  WHERE CLIENT.CLIENTNO = TOTALS.CLIENTNO 
  ORDER BY TOTALS.TOTAL DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753936/fetching-data-using-rownum-in-oracle/7754076#7754076

Comment: @rahularyansharma. Nice link. It's not really related, though, is it?

Comment: @EliaWeiss: This question is about Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the rownum where in another external query:

```
select * from (
SELECT CLIENT.CLIENTNO, CLIENT.CNAME, TOTALS.TOTAL 
FROM CLIENT, (SELECT CLIENTNO, SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL FROM PURCHASE GROUP BY CLIENTNO) TOTALS 
WHERE CLIENT.CLIENTNO = TOTALS.CLIENTNO ORDER BY TOTALS.TOTAL DESC)
where ROWNUM <= 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the MySQL people that find this, use ROW_NUMBER() to get the same result with:

```
WITH ranked AS (    
        SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY CLIENTNO
            ORDER BY TOTALS.TOTALS
        ) ROWNUM,
       CLIENT.CLIENTNO,
       .
       . )
SELECT * FROM ranked
    WHERE ROWNUM <=1
```

Some helpful info: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number