# Alternate for decode function

Tags: oracle

I have a table 'Holiday' which lists a set of holiday details.If i specify a date,I should obtain a result date after 5 days of specified date.If there is holiday in between it should exclude them and display the non holiday date.I have table named holiday which includes holiday date,holiday type|(weekly off,local holiday).Now i have used nested decode for continuous holiday checking.**Tell me how this can be changed in case function.**

```
DECODE
               (date,
                holidaydate, DECODE
                   (date + 1,
                    holidaydate + 1, DECODE
                       (date + 2,
                        holidaydate + 2, DECODE
                           (date + 3,holidaydate+3,date+4,date+3),date+2),date+1),date);
```

Comment: show us some code of what you've done, then we might be able to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there really is no information in the question that I can use to help you. What is your current "decode function", why is it insufficient? Why do you think you need an alternate decode function? I'd love to help, but haven't given us enough (any) detail.

Comment: `CASE` function, you're probably asking for `CASE`, in oracle, there are CASE statements, and CASE expressions.

Comment: actually i have table holiday listing holidays.I have a procedure to find next non holiday.sample code is                        select date decode(date,holdate,decode(date+1,holdate+1,decode(date+2,holdate+2,holdate+3),holdate+2),holdate+1),holdate);

Comment: @RobPresto It is still not clear what you want. Edit the question with table details, sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the optimal solution.Thanks for ur response guys. `SELECT dt FROM 
    (SELECT dt FROM (SELECT TO_DATE('15-AUG-2013','dd-mon-yyyy')+LEVEL dt FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 30)

            WHERE 
             (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM mst_holiday WHERE holidaydate = dt) = 0 )
             where rownum=1`

Comment: I advise you to use `fetch first 1 rows only` instead of `rownum`, this pseudo-column has some limitations and is cumbersome to use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7754076/458157

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved with a simple subquery which counts the number of holiday dates between a specified date and date+5.  The following will return a date that is five non-holiday days in the future:

```
testdate+(select 5+count(1) 
            from holiday
           where holidaydate between testdate
                                 and testdate + 5)
```

Simply change both "5"s so another number to change the evaluation period.

[SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c2d72/4/0)

**Edit** - based on comment below, my code doesn't evaluate any days after the fifth day.  This would probably be much easier with a function, but the following cte-based code will work also:

```
with cte as ( (select alldate,holidaydate 
                 from (select to_date('20130101','yyyymmdd')+level alldate 
                         from dual 
                       connect by level < 10000 -- adjust for period to evaluate
                      ) alldates 
                      left join holiday on alldate=holidaydate) )
select 
    testdate,test_plus_five
from ( 
    select 
        alldate test_plus_five,testdate,
        sum(case when holidaydate is null 
                 then 1 
                 else 0 end) over (partition by testdate order by alldate) lastday 
    from 
        cte,
        testdates
    where
        alldate >= testdate
    group by
        alldate,holidaydate,testdate)
where
    lastday = 6
```

This script builds a calendar table so it can evaluate each day (holiday or non-holiday); then we get a running count of non-holiday days, and use the sixth one.

[SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/553af/1/0)

Comment: What if the adjusted date is also a holiday? I added 2013-09-08 as a holiday and the third test date, 2013-08-31, [still picks that day](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b82bc/1).

Comment: You're right -- good catch.  That makes it much more complex.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, You can use `CASE` alternative to `DECODE` in Oracle

```
CASE [ expression ]

   WHEN condition_1 THEN result_1
   WHEN condition_2 THEN result_2
   ...
   WHEN condition_n THEN result_n

   ELSE result

END
```

Comment: Any reason why not `CASE`?

Comment: i need an alternate like procedures other than case!