# why we cannot use condition rownum=5 in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I observed that rownum can be used as follows:

```
1)  select * from emp where rownum<5;
2)  select * from emp where rownum<=5;
3)  select * from emp where rownum=1;
```

All this queries return expected output. Say table emp has 7 rows then 1st query returns 4 rows, 2nd returns 5 rows ,3rd returns 1 row. 
But when I try to use something like:

```
4)  select * from emp where rownum=5;
5)  select * from emp where rownum>5;
6)  select * from emp where rownum>=5;
7)  select * from emp where rownum between 5 and 10;
```

In all this cases, it returns 0 rows. Why this is so? Is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: This is well explained in the manual: "*Conditions testing for ROWNUM values greater than a positive integer are always false*" see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns009.htm#i1006297

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something similar like this:

```
select * from (
  select
    emp.*,
    row_number() over (order by fieldname) as rnum
  from emp
) tmp
where
  rnum between 5 and 10;
```

Comment: You can use row_number in where clause.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan You can't use analytic functions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: yes, it can be done using analytic function as you suggested , but it would have been a lot better if oracle could have allowed as asked in question.

Comment: @chammu, not really, as then ROWNUM would no longer do what ROWNUM is supposed to do.

Answer (score 7):

This is because rownum is a pseudo column and it counts rows in the result set after you apply the where clause.

From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255):-

> Conditions testing for ROWNUM values greater than a positive integer
>   are always false. For example, this query returns no rows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM employees
  WHERE ROWNUM > 1;
```

**The first row fetched is assigned a ROWNUM of 1 and makes the condition false.** The second row to be fetched is now the first row and is also assigned a ROWNUM of 1 and makes the condition false. All rows subsequently fail to satisfy the condition, so no rows are returned.

You can also use ROWNUM to assign unique values to each row of a table, as in this example:

```
UPDATE my_table
  SET column1 = ROWNUM;
```

You may find these references helpfull:-

- [Using ROWNUM in Oracle](http://blog.lishman.com/2008/03/rownum.html)
- [SQL Query With Row_Number, order by and where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834702/sql-query-with-row-number-order-by-and-where-clause)